# SOAP Request with HTTP Client with client certification connection timed out Exception

Tags: java, ssl, soap

I am trying to hit an url with client certification have generate key with:

```
keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keystore /example.jks -validity 10950
```

and key store with:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias root -file /example.cer -keystore /example.jks
```

and trying to connect:

```
System.out.println("------------------------------------------- In         SendRequest ------------------------------------################");
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
Certificate cert=getCertificate();
URL url = new URL("url");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
HttpsURLConnection httpsUrlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection;
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = getFactory();
httpsUrlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
DataOutputStream wr = new         DataOutputStream(httpsUrlConnection.getOutputStream());
System.out.println(wr.toString());
File req_xml = new File("request.xml");
//SOAPMessage req = TestCase.createSoapSubsribeRequest("SUBSCRIBE");
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");
post.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(req_xml), req_xml.length()));
post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
//post.setHeader("SOAPAction", "");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

LOG.info("************************************************************RESPONSE****************"+response.getStatusLine());
// SOAP response(xml) get        String res_xml = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    LOG.info("Response"+res_xml);
}
private SSLSocketFactory getFactory( )  {
    try{ 
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------- In getFactory ------------------------------------################");
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        //InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
        String password = "obsmesh";
                    char[] passwd = password.toCharArray(example.jks");
        keystore.load(is, passwd);
        // keyInput.close();
        keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, password.toCharArray());
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------- In jsdkl ------------------------------------################");
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManager[] trust = null;
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
        return context.getSocketFactory();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
return null;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code I hope it  will help you.

```
     KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
            .loadTrustMaterial(new File("//your jks file path "), "//key password here",
                    new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[] { "TLSv1" },
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    try {


     File req_xml = new File("// your request xml file path");


   HttpPost post = new HttpPost("//https client url");
   post.setEntity(new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(req_xml), req_xml.length()));
   post.setHeader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + post.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            System.out.println(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks It  Worked For me